# How to set the text alignment in picker view iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to set the alignment of the text in picker view but my solutions doesn't work.
This is my code so far. I used array to store values on the picker view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];

self.source = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
               initWithObjects:@"  5   Minutes", @"10   Minutes", @"15   Minutes", @"20   Minutes",@"25   Minutes",@"30   Minutes",@"35   Minutes",@"40   Minutes",@"45   Minutes",@"50   Minutes",@"55   Minutes",@"60   Minutes", nil];

self.picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 275.0, 320.0, 120.0)];


self.picker.delegate = self;
self.picker.dataSource = self;

[self.view addSubview:self.picker];
[self.picker selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:YES];}
```

then,

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return [source objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
 return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return [source count];
}
```

However, it works fine when it displays the values. But when I align the text at the center,  instead of displaying the text(values on picker view), the picker view becomes empty. This is the code on how I've done the alignment at the center.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 37)];
 //label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"something here"];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
return label;
}
```

What might be the solution for this?
Please help me regarding this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: For UIPickerView you need to use either titleForRow: method or viewForRow: method. You cannot use both methods at the same time.

Comment: Ok. So where I can put the 'UiTextAlignmentCenter' for UIPickerView if I used the titleForRow method?

Comment: You have to use viewForRow: method and return the UILabel with UITextAlignment property as center. Or you can use my DPickerView(http://dineshrajas.github.io/DPickerView/) in github. It gives you the centered text as default.

Comment: Hmm. I see now the difference between titleForRow and viewForRow methods. I will use now the viewForRow as you recommended. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i done with this code for UIlabel text show in center of tableView like:-

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 37)];

        if (component == 0) {

            label.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22];
            label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [source objectAtIndex:row]];
        label.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22];

        }
    [label autorelease];
    return label;
 }
```

**Code output is**

[image]

Comment: Many thanks to you Nitin Gohel. It Works great!. I accepted your answer but for now I cant vote up since I have no reputation points yet. I will get back on this to vote up soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For swift 3 we can use

```
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code instead of your code..

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{

    UIView *viewTemp = [[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44)]autorelease];
    [viewTemp setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    UILabel *lbl = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 300, 37)]autorelease];
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lbl setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22]];
    lbl.text = @"Some Text";
    [lbl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [viewTemp addSubview:lbl];
    return viewTemp;
}
```

Here i return one `UIView` in which i add `UILable` see above code so your whole view display with `UILable` properly and also set backGroundColor of `UIView` is clear so its display layout of `UIPickerView`.

I also display star like text in this `UIPickerView`.

See images Bellow..

[image][image]

Comment: how did you created UIPickerView with rating stars ??

Comment: i just set that rateView as a `UIView` in `viewForRow:` method of UIPickerView's delegate method.

Comment: yes i just add that DYRateView in UIPickerView.. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```